# Call procedure that has no sender

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i'm trying to call a `procedure ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);` but when i call it `ListBox1DrawItem(Control)` or whatever i put there, it shows up `undeclarated identifier`

Can someone help with this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your scenario. First, if this is a `TListBox`'s `OnDrawItem` handler, it must be `procedure TSomething.ListBox1DrawItem(...)`. Second, you obviously cannot do `ListBox1DrawItem(Control)` since you must provide all four parameters. Finally, and most importantly, you are not supposed to call this method at all. Windows will call it, via the VCL, when it needs to repaint the item. But if for some reason you still "need" to call it, you can pass, for instance, `ListBox1` as the control. That's probably the one you want (but I cannot see your code).

Comment: Yep, sorry, my bad. It has `TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState)` 
Secondary, i don't even know what should i put into the ().

Comment: Well, as I wrote, you shouldn't need to call `ListBox1DrawItem` at all. You are not supposed to call this procedure: *Windows* will (indirectly) call it when it is time to repaint the item. So, since you don't need to call this procedure, you don't need to know what parameters to pass it! :) Still, if, for some strange reason, you have structured your code so that you really do need to call it (in which case you should refactor), you can pass the relevant list box control, likely `ListBox1`.

Comment: @Pheggas please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the "undeclared identifier" error.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnDrawItem` handler is a method of your `TForm1` class, so you need to call it on a valid `TForm1` object, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl;
  Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  ...
end;

procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
begin
  ...
  {Self.}ListBox1DrawItem(ListBox1, DesiredIndexGoesHere, Rect(Desired,Values,Go,Here), DesiredStateGoesHere);
  ...
end;
```

If you want to call `ListBox1DrawItem()` from another class, you still need access to the `TForm1` object, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Unit1;

procedure TForm2.DoSomething;
begin
  ...
  Form1.ListBox1DrawItem(Form1.ListBox1, DesiredIndexGoesHere, Rect(Desired,Values,Go,Here), DesiredStateGoesHere);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is a perfectly legit answer to the question asked. It may not be the best design choice, but it does work. That is not grounds to downvote.

Comment: A more appropriate approach would be to have the event handler call another method. And then code that is not part of the VCL framework can call that other method. As a basic principle, only the framework should call event handlers directly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm aware of that approach, but even doing that does not address the OP's question regarding the "undeclared identifier" error. Such a method would be in the same scope as `ListBox1DrawItem` and would likewise be undeclared in the scope where the OP is trying to call it.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP (post) and its comments is that the OP (poster) doesn't know what to pass as the `Control` parameter. But the Q is indeed very unclear.

Comment: (But I didn't downvote, just for the record.)